# Insert into on duplicate key update current time stamp

Tags: mysql, sql

Both tables have the same structure:

```
Url: unique key
date: current time stamp
projectname: text column
```

Here is the sql command i am trying to run:

```
INSERT INTO urldup (url, date, projectname)
Select url, date, projectname
From sample_temp s1
ON Duplicate key update date=s1.date
```

When there are duplicate url's i would like to update the date column to the date a insert was tried.

I can insert non duplicates fine with the above query but cannot update the row date if there is a duplicate match.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for `on duplicate key update` to work, you have to have a unique key.  Create a unique index on `url`:

```
create unique index sampletemp_url on sample_temp(url)
```

Then, when you try to insert a duplicate, the date will be updated.

Then, your statement is setting the date to the date *already in the record*.  You want to use `now()` instead:

```
INSERT INTO urldup (url, date, projectname)
    Select url, date, projectname
    From sample_temp s1
    ON Duplicate key update date = now();
```

Comment: Even though the url column is set to unique it still doesn't update the timestamp.